# Why a tuple is greater than a similar list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there any reason why the next tuple is greater then the list?

```
>>> t = ( 1, 2, 3 )
>>> l = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
>>> t > l
True
>>> t < l
False
```

Comment: In Python 3.x, this is invalid, and will throw a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Python 2, any tuple is always compared as greater than any list - that's just the way it is defined in the language.

In Python 3, this is fixed, so that comparing tuples and lists gives `TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() > list()`.

Comment: This maybe isn't necessary since the answer is clear, but where can you find this in the docs?

Comment: For reference...: `sorted([dict, set, frozenset, tuple, list])` gives `[<type 'set'>, <type 'frozenset'>, <type 'dict'>, <type 'list'>, <type 'tuple'>]` - so apparently the tuple is the greatest of the types! :)

Comment: Well it's not accurate for Python2. It is in fact [implementation dependent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20998315/2642204), not defined in the language.

Answer (score 9):

No there is no good reason for this, and it is confusing, which is why it doesn't work like that in Python 3.