# Why is tuple larger than a list in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Consider following problem in Python:

```
>>> () < []
```

this statement yield `False` and

```
>>> () > []
```

yields True. So far as I know, `[]` equals `False`, but what is an empty tuple ?

If we type

```
>>> 1233 < (1,2)
```

We get a `True`, as return value. But why ?

Thanks

Comment: Only `True` in python2.

Comment: @user995394 http://ideone.com/10x5fN

Comment: @BartoszKP That's python2, so? http://ideone.com/sMggNX

Comment: @user995394 You said it gives only `True` whereas in the link I gave it's clearly `False`.

Comment: Have look into the python's source code. Probably the answer will be based on that. Has nothing to do with general programming if you think you will encounter this behavior in other languages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why a tuple is greater than a similar list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092016/why-a-tuple-is-greater-than-a-similar-list)

Comment: @BartoszKP I don't see why, look at the comments...

Comment: `[]` doesn't *equal* `False`. It logically evaluates to `False`, as does `()`. So `bool(()) == bool([])` returns `True`

Comment: @MaximeLorant Answer in the linked question is inaccurate. This is implementation dependent (see [my](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20998315/2642204) and other answers for example), not "defined in the language").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> The operators <, >, ==, >=, <=, and != compare the values of two
>   objects. The objects need not have the same type. If both are numbers,
>   they are converted to a common type. Otherwise, objects of different
>   types always compare unequal, and are ordered consistently but
>   arbitrarily. You can control comparison behavior of objects of
>   non-builtin types by defining a `__cmp__` method or rich comparison
>   methods like `__gt__`, described in section 3.4.
>
> (This unusual definition of comparison was used to simplify the
>   definition of operations like sorting and the in and not in operators.
>   **In the future, the comparison rules for objects of different types are
>   likely to change.)**

Which is true.  In python 3 this is a `TypeError`.

```
() > []
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d2326cfc55a3> in <module>()
----> 1 () > []

TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() > list()
```

Back to python 2: The docs stress that this is an *arbitrary, but consistent* ordering.

In [cPython](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) 2, unequal types are compared by their type name.  So `tuple` is "greater than" `list`, lexicographically.

Answer (score 2):

This is a CPython (2.x) implementation detail, as documented in [Built-in Types - Comparisons](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons):

> **CPython implementation detail**: Objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address.

Therefore, any tuple compares greater than any list because `'tuple' > 'list'`.

This no longer holds in CPython 3, and has never held for other implementations of Python 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> Most other objects of built-in types compare unequal unless they are the same object; the choice whether one object is considered smaller or larger than another one is made arbitrarily but consistently within one execution of a program.

So it seems to be implementation dependent. For example in [CPython](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons):

> Objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address.

Answer (score 0):

This could be implementation dependent and I think there is no direct reason for this.
Python 3.X prohibits comparison between two different Types all together.

Answer (score 0):

This is, because python 2.x uses the method `__cmp__()`.
Python 3.x won't use this method.

You are using a python version lower than 3.0.
With python version 3.x, there will be an exception:
TypeError: unorderalbe types ...